# Почему "дизлайки", а не "дислайки"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, орфоэпия

Вопрос к Галине и всем остальным.

Почему вы считаете правильным вариант *"ди**з**лайки"* (вместо *"ди**с**лайков"*) несмотря на то, что по-английски это слово звучит через /s/ ([dislike](https://forvo.com/word/dislike/#en))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В правилах англо-русской практической транскрипции нет однозначно рекомендованного порядка (напр. с ориентацией только на реальное произношение). Если использовать википедию как подручный источник, для s формально допускаются оба варианта (с и з), без оговорок напр. для сочетания sl. Слово "дислайк" стало употребляться гораздо позже "лайков" - возможно, сведующие люди его со временем "устаканят", как и "приговорят" навязываемое программистами "й" в слове "биткоин": преодолели же со временем чтение известной фамилии Townshend как "Тауншенд", возникшее из учебно-книжных представлений (правильно Таунсенд при реальном "Таунзенд" - русская версия учитывает различие в смежных звуках n и н); перестали и импланты с имплантатами путать. Сейчас вот в СМИ по наитию "брек**с**ит" (вторая часть слова - от exit, выход) зачастую "брек**з**итом" именуют - это неестественно потому, что второй вариант произношения - американский, а явление - чисто британское, слово в оригинальном английском возникло (в котором "эксит", а не "эгзит" с "эгзитполами").

**P.S.** Если обратиться к формальным правилам для данной приставки греческого происхождения. http://dist.ffl.msu.ru/dc/rus/orf_p14.htm Перед *любой* согласной пишется приставка *ди**с-***, в то время как её альтернатива *ди**з**/дез* пишется перед гласной или твёрдым знаком. В этом смысле (если образовывать слово в русском) "дизлайк" - орфографическая ошибка.

Comment: Интересно, даже не слышал фамилии с H, единственную слышал американскую теннисистку Taylor Townsend. Как думаете, неправильно её записали, как Хуана Эчеварри́ю вместо "Эчеверрия"?

Comment: Есть и такое (без Н) написание фамилии с тем же произношением. Я имел в виду знаменитого музыканта группы Who. Когда-то была доступна только письменная информация собложек дисков, и даже такие муз. журналисты, как Артемий Троицкий, затруднялись правильно воспроизвести её в русском.

Comment: Я, к своему стыду, очень плохо знаком с the Who. Послушаю как-нибудь и, может, почитаю что-то про музыкантов.

Comment: *...перестали и импланты с имплантатами путать.* Так это одно и то же или нет?

Comment: У стоматологов - одно и то же, но в интересах единства русскоязычной терминологии (она сложилась в общей имплантологии), которая традиционно восходит к немецкоязычным источникам, правильнее "имплантат". Первое время у стоматологов бытовало исключительно "имплант" (из английской сопроводительной документации), но со временем (даже по рекламе услуг) заметно движение традиционному "имплантат".

Comment: Любопытно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что буква С не звучит перед буквой Л (именно в этой приставке, которая означает "анти"). Я не смотрел ни в один словарь или справочник перед тем, как выбрать букву. Л - звонкий звук, и хочется, чтобы с ним рядом был тоже звонкий (З).

Слово уже в словарях зафиксировано:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/дизлайк](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA)

А вообще, у этой приставки есть два варианта. Не думаю, что будут смотреть на оригинал.

Вспоминаем примеры со звуком "л": безликий, безлесный, безлюдный. Что ж, вроде бы все очевидно. Руководствуясь этим правилом, пишем "дизлайк".
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/litinteres/kak-pravilno-dizlaik-ili-dislaik-5a8060da168a91730221bf64

Звук З, являясь резким, как бы подчёркивает отрицание лайка. А звук С - спокойный, "уравновешенный".

Comment: *...хочется, чтобы с ним рядом был тоже звонкий.* Но есть же "дислокация", "дислексия". @Alex_ander: кстати, знаете, британцы и Иснера (теннисиста) через с произносят, и мне так тоже нравится. А у нас почему-то его только через З пишут и называют.

Comment: В "дислокации" нет значения "анти", нет отрицания. Думаю, что "дизлайк" просто совпал с правилом приставки "без", которое основано на звонких/глухих. (Люди так решили.) И ещё, "дислексию" (у которой приставка другая - dyslexia), похоже, учёные переводили. А "дизлайк" - обычные пользователи соцсетей.

Comment: В противовес вики-статье с пометкой "текущая версия не проверялась", я дополнил свой ответ ссылкой на правила.

Comment: @Alex_ander Да я читал уже это правило. Но вы же знаете, что в правилах часто бывают исключения. Полтора миллиона результатов против ста тысяч, в которых часто "дислайк, а точнее дизлайк". Кто прав: правило или общество?

Comment: А вот вики, в которой предлагают оба варианта: http://wikireality.ru/wiki/Дислайк

Answer (score 0):

Студент мехфака, больше компьютерный глист, английское requirements читал как [рекЬЮрментс] - не умел он по-другому, но к концу курса (экзамен же!) таки отучился. Патриархи Интернета вспомнят и "брОУзер" 90-х. Хотя "рОУтер" из router вроде еще живет. Пришло в голову надавнее Lamborghini как [ламборДЖини] - сейчас уже, кажется, окончательно исправилось на [Г]. А "девчёнка" (как "тушёнка"), и даже "чят" - как вам? Английские слова можно бы и в словаре глянуть, или послушать от носителей на Ютюбе. А безграмотное "диЗлайк" ленивого общества - в исключения? Туда же и "пати" (party), и еще кучу слов-уродцев из чятов.

Comment: Не знаю, "пати" мне нравится в плане произношения, другое дело, что и так есть слово "вечеринка", оно лучше для нас.